# Can't connect from host to Redis running inside Docker container on custom port

Tags: docker, redis

I'm trying to connect to Redis, running inside a Docker container, from the host machine (macOS).

As I locally have a Redis instance running via homebrew, I've tried to map the Docker container's Redis to port 6380 instead of 6379. (Can I just do something like that?)

```
➜ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
96c36ee47c62        redis:5.0.6-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   41 seconds ago      Up 39 seconds       6379/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6379->6380/tcp   redis
```

When I stop the locally running version of Redis and map the container port to 6379 I'm able to connect to the container via `redis-cli`. But with the custom 6380 port I just get an error:

```
➜ redis-cli -p 6380
`Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6380: Connection refused not connected>` error.
```

I've started the container with the following command

```
➜ docker run --name redis -d -p 6379:6380 --network mynetwork redis:5.0.6-alpine
```

What is the reason that I can't connect on the other port? Thank you.

Comment: The Docker-private IP addresses don't work in a variety of situations; for instance, if you're on a MacOS or Windows host, those addresses don't work.  I'd use one of the other ways of communicating with them – the container name as a host name between containers, the published port from the host.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for the information. After posting the question I've realized that there was a local Redis version running on the default port. As I actually tried to use a differnt port before, I've updated the question to be more clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I've confused the "inner" and "outer" port. Instead of

`-p 6379:6380` it should have been:

`-p 6380:6379`.

Now it works as expected.